# How to add labels to pie charts in amCharts?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

The following is the function used to generate a pie chart. Everything is working fine, except for the **addLabel** parameter.

```
graphSentiChart:function(graphData) {
    if(graphData.length < 1){
      $('.dataContentStatsPie').html('No data available')
    }
    // $(".dataContentAllPie").empty();
    var piechart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartPie", {
        "type": "pie",
        "theme": "light",
        "autoMargins": true,
        "marginTop": 0,
        "marginBottom": 10,
        "marginLeft": 0,
        "marginRight": 0,
        "dataProvider": graphData,
        "titleField":"key",
        "valueField": "value",
        "addLabel": (0, 25, 'Total Tweets= 360'),
        "startDuration":0,
         "responsive": {
            "enabled":true
         },
         "legend":{
           "autoMargins":false,
           "marginLeft":20,
            "enabled": true,
            "spacing":20,
            "markerType":"circle",
            "horizontalGap" :20,

         },
          "labelsEnabled":false,
        //"balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",

        "colorField": "color",
        "innerRadius": "60%",

        "export": {
            "enabled": true,
            "libs": {
                "path": "http://amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/libs/"
            }

        }
    });
```

What I have given in the addLabel parameter is not being taken and the label is also not getting shown. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property in amCharts `addLabel`. There is a [method](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#addLabel), which can be used to add labels to an already existing chart object.

To specify labels in the JSON config of the chart, use [`allLabels`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#allLabels):

```
"allLabels": [{
  "x": 0,
  "y": 25,
  "text": "Total Tweets= 360"
}]
```

Comment: Thanks. allLabels is working fine. 
I read about addLabel from amChart documentation [here](https://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/AmChart#addLabel)

I was reading the documentation for amCharts version 2.

Comment: Here is the solution to add custom label and text in amchart v3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340060/how-to-divide-amchart-pie-chart-using-time-duration